# Kafka Replication - Source and Sink Databases Not Matching Recordcount

Tags: apache-kafka, conduktor

I am replicating data from SQL Server to Postgres via source and sink connectors configured in Conduktor. I have noticed that the recordcount for one table in SQL Server does not match the recordcount for the replicated table in Postgres. I have tried removing the connectors, backed up the table and renamed it, and then re-added the connectors, but this has still not resolved the issue. Is there something else I can try?

Comment: How are you calculating the difference? And how much is the difference between two? Syncing would have eventual consistency problem

Comment: The difference in sql recordcount between the source and sink is 9 records. Source - 90679 / Sink - 90670.

Comment: those 9 records were completely missed? or later if you try again they are inserted by the sinker?

Comment: Also took the following steps to re-initialized the Kafka source connector:
1 - Removed the source connector
2 - Reset the source offsets for this connector
3 - Created the source connector again.

After doing the above we have found that the source db has 1 less record than the target so I am trying to figure out why.

Should we also remove and re-create the sink as well?

Comment: When you take the count of the records is there any operation happening on the DB? Is this a production application?

Comment: There is no operation happening on the DB. We've checked with the database admins and they only run index/builds on a specific day. When we look at the timestamp for the missing records that dont make it into Postgres we see timestamps on pretty much any day of the week and this occurs randomly throughout the day. Yes this is happening in production